# Zoho CRM API 400 Bad Request (duplicate_record) when adding a new lead which is already converted to a contact & deal

Tags: crm, zoho

I am trying to create a new lead into Zoho CRM using the RestAPI V5, the problem happens when the Lead is already converted to a contact & deal.
Before creating any new lead , I search for the lead using the email field which is a unique field , but it returns nothing as the lead is already converted to a contact.
how can I search for the lead using email address even if it is converted , and know that it is converted?

```
Client error: `POST https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v5/Leads` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"data":[{"code":"DUPLICATE_DATA","details":{"api_name":"Email","duplicate_record":...
```